# The tag [windows-virtual-pc] should be merged with [virtual-pc]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request, tag-synonym-request

I noticed that there are two tags for Microsoft Virtual PC, of which one is [virtual-pc](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/virtual-pc) (327 questions) and the other is [windows-virtual-pc](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-virtual-pc) (7 questions). Windows Virtual PC is referring to a specific version of Microsoft Virtual PC. The tags should be merged into a central tag, say [microsoft-virtual-pc](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-virtual-pc).

Comment: Would it make more sense to merge these both into [microsoft-virtual-pc] so that it's clear that it's the product that is being talked about, and not the abstract concept of a virtual pc?

Comment: @DarthAndroid We already have [tag:virtual-machine] to represent the abstract concept...

Comment: [virtual-pc] is ambigious. But AFAIR the official name of the program is now Windows Virtual PC which is ambigious too, so maybe sticking to [ms-virtual-pc] or [microsoft-virtual-pc] would be the best choice.

Comment: @gronostaj I think that it would be best to make [microsoft-virtual-pc the central tag.

Comment: Please don't flag above comments as obsolete. This is Meta – discussion is *welcome* and it's not like we're drowning in comments unrelated to the question. Keeping the comments doesn't do any harm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done

```
updating post history, 445 rows affected
updating posts, 327 rows affected
removing/renaming old tag, 1 rows affected
updating count for master tag, 1 rows affected
tag remapping of [microsoft-virtual-pc] and [virtual-pc] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
17 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
Tag Synonym virtual-pc -> microsoft-virtual-pc was approved!
Broadcasting tag-engine reload
```

---

```
updating post history, 8 rows affected
updating posts, 7 rows affected
updating PostTags associations, 3 rows affected
removing/renaming old tag, 0 rows affected
updating count for master tag, 1 rows affected
tag remapping of [microsoft-virtual-pc] and [windows-virtual-pc] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
0 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
Tag Synonym windows-virtual-pc -> microsoft-virtual-pc was approved!
Broadcasting tag-engine reload
```